# Compilation error _atoid

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I'm learnin C and I'm having trouble running this code, it is from the book head first C, and it is exactly as in the book. I alsol tryed to compile it on ubuntu and I got a similar error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
    int val = 0;
    char card_name[3];
    puts ("Enter Card Name: ");
    scanf("%2s", card_name);
    if (card_name[0] == 'Q') {
    val = 10;
    }
    else if (card_name[0] == 'J') {
    val = 10;
    } 
    else if (card_name[0] == 'A') {
    val = 11;
    }
    else if (card_name[0] == 'K') {
    val = 10;
    }
    else {
    val = atoid(card_name);
    }
    printf("The card value if: %i\n", val);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error.

```
C:\Users\LL\Documents>cl cards.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.61030 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cards.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:cards.exe
cards.obj
cards.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _atoid referenced in funct
ion _main
cards.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: atoi without the d at the end I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atoid function doesn't exist in the standard lib, you (or the book) probably meant atoi, which is a function that turns a string to a integer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c.aspx

Btw personal advice, try to indent any code between brackets. Way more readable.